# Calling a function twice where return string information doesn't change

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, playwright

I have written a front-end automation test in Javascript for a web application where you create a new user using an email address, the user logs in, logs out and then logs back into a system using the same email address detail you initially created.

I have the following function in Javascript for this. When I call this function in the same class it returns the following email string "email1615148555@example.com".
When this function is called again in another class the 'ts' part changes because of a change in time.

How do I code it so that I can use the same return email address the second time in another class in the same test?

Please note that each time the test itself runs a unique email address is generated.

```
func() {
        var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        var consumerEmail = config.email + ts + "@example.com";
        return consumerEmail.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Is `func` inside a class?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Yes it is inside a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the logic into 2 separate functions and reuse the timestamp across multiple calls.

```js
const timestamp = () => Math.round(new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

function test(timestamp) {
    return config.email + timestamp + "@example.com";
}

const ts = timestamp()

test(ts)
test(ts)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Implement memorise concept to achieve the expected result

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-memoize-in-javascript-51d07d19430e/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton service for that and do something like this:

```
var consumerEmail = new (function () {

  var consumerEmail = "";

   this.get = function() {
     if (!consumerEmail){
       var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
       consumerEmail = config.email + ts + "@example.com";
     }

     return consumerEmail.toString();
  }
})();
```

And then call it:

```
getConsumerEmail.get();
```